# Capybara: are cookies saved in a scraping session?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, capybara, recaptcha

I've built a program to automate posting ads on craigslist using ruby and capybara. As i recall, it would visit the craigslist URL, log me in, then post a job ad and close the browser, wait 30 minutes then repeat for a total of 3 times. What was curious was that it had to retype my login credentials ever single time.

I'm wondering if cookies get saved after closing the browser during a scraping session, and if it is possible to save these cookies so it wouldn't have to keep logging in each time.

The reason for this is that I modified an existing program to automate job applications on indeed.com but I keep running into the new recaptcha security feature. I would solve the recaptcha image manually (about 5 times until it lets me through), then it would apply to the job and then close the browser. It would open again to apply to the next job and let me pass without a recaptcha test, then the job after that it would pop up again and ask me for around 5-10 recaptcha tests.

So my theory is that saving cookies would at least help in reducing the frequency of these recaptcha tests. Is it possible to do that? am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capybara doesn't save any cookies between sessions itself. You can manually write code to save the cookies and reload them using driver specific methods, or you can look at [show me the cookies](https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies)  https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies for a cross browser API for getting and creating cookies. I do wonder why you're closing the browser in between each application though?  Why not just keep it open and reuse the same session?

Comment: I didn't write the code myself and i'm a very amateur programmer. When I commented out page.close so the software can just loop to `visit = @page.url the program just froze. Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: @user3787179 Without seeing the code or knowing what exactly it's doing I can't really diagnose the hang - however you could always try visiting some other url (www.google.com for instance) at the end of your loop before revisiting craigslist.